# Windows Service Setup Project Problems Converting From VS.NET 2008 to 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, installation

I'm trying to convert a solution from VS.NET 2008 to 2010. The solution includes a Windows Service project and a Setup project that installs the Windows Service. I'm having trouble compiling the Setup project. I've tried starting this over from scratch a few times, following the tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) under the section titled **To create a setup project for your service**.

When I simply follow these steps and build the project, I get this error:

```
Unable to build custom action named 'Primary output from <name> (Release x86)', InstallerClass property is only valid for assemblies.
```

(where  is the name of my Windows Service project). A search for this error brings up [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/447a3y7x%28VS.71%29.aspx) page on MSDN which tells me to set **InstallerClass** to **False**. I do so for each of the 4 Custom Actions. After making this change and building, I get the following error:

```
Unable to build custom action named 'Primary output from <name> (Release x86)' from project output group 'Primary output' because the project output group does not have a key file.
```

Googling for that, I only get a single [hit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eys6tc94%28VS.71%29.aspx). Don't even bother clicking the link, the full text is: "Remove the custom action and replace it with a custom action pointing to a project output group that has a key file."

What the h does that mean? Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the problem was when I set **InstallerClass** to **False**. Apparently, I hadn't built the Windows Service for the x86 target. I got the hint from [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/49aab885-26fc-4c49-b370-0f56570a2f2b) discussion. I changed all of the projects to target the correct platform and left **InstallerClass** set to **True** for each of the Custom Actions in the setup file and it's building now.

Comment: Where is this `InstallerClass` property to set to true?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan In VS 2103, double click error in error list, under Install folder you guys, then you should see InstallerClass property in properties window to set to false.

Answer (score 3):

This is kinda old but just ran into this error myself:
Migrated vs2008 to vs2010, setup project did not give error in one specific config but did in 2 other configs that included the setup project.  Found that when originally created, someone had Added primary output from a specific configuration (Not "(Active)").  So when a different config was built, setup would throw this error.  (probably had this problem prior to migration to vs2010.)
To fix:

1. Copy custom actions names and CustomActionData strings (just text to recreate easily)
2. Delete custom actions
3. Delete primary output & content files (this was web setup project)
4. Add back in primary & content, selecting (Active) config
5. Add back custom actions

Now it all builds without error.

Comment: Sometimes all you need to do is rebuild all the components to make sure they are available especially when switching from debug to release.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild the project which class installer class individually, and then rebuild the installer project.