# Custom Action, Unable to build custom action because the project output group does not have a key file

Tags: c#, installation, custom-action

When I am trying to create an installation project, I get this error message when I try to build the installation class.

**Unable to build custom action  because the project output group does not have a key file.**

What is wrong my custom action

I have a custom action that does some manipulation after the 
 I have a custom action as follows.

```
  public class InstallerHelper:Installer
  {
    public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
      base.Install(stateSaver);
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3151435/57787

Answer (score 0):

Within your installation project, you need to identify a key file in the Project Output group that you have referenced.

To resolve the issue, right-click on the appropriate project output that you have added to the installation program, expand the `KeyOutput` node, and click in the `(Files)` box and click the `...` button.

If there is nothing in there, then you should probably remove that output from your installer.